# Efficient algorithm to find a $C_{k}$ in an undirected graph, that has no $C_{k-1}$

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Suppose that $G = (V, E)$ is an undirected graph, and $G$ is promised not to contain $C_{k-1}$.

Goal is to find any $C_k$ in $G$ using an efficient algorithm. Efficient, in this scope, meaning that finding all cycles and excluding all $C_{m>k}$ is out of question.

First thing comes in mind is to use depth-first search, and return if a cycle is found.

Since the problem is not finding *all* the $C_k$s, the algorithm should run approximately in $\mathcal{O}(|V| + |E|)$.
Is this really lower bound, or do we need an algorithm that has higher asymptotic bound?

Comment: Thank you for the notice and warning. I have modified the question and made it more general.

Comment: The edit changes the question.  What is $k$?  is it a fixed constant?  Or is it part of the input?

Comment: It's a variable that is part of the input

Comment: The question is vague, please elaborate (What is Ck? What is C? What is k?)